# using spring social with struts2

Tags: facebook, struts2, spring-social

I am trying to using spring-social in my java web application
from here http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/

But i am using struts2 for MVC and not spring mvc so can any one 
please tell how to use spring social with struts2

Comment: have you found a solution ? I'm having the same issue!

Comment: I have same problem ?
@user2894360 If you found any solution then post in answer Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use it is to create a maven project. The spring social itself depends on spring framework.it is just you are using Struts mvc instead spring mvc you will write code in action classes. So it is better to use maven to get all dependencies in the project by just adding

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

for facebook

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.social-facebook-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and other dependecies you can find on [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/overview.html)
and write in pom.xml and get started with any online tutorial.

For example

1.> http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/connecting.html

2.> http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-social-tutorial/

Comment: he is using Struts2 therefore he can not access the spring social classes easily.